# "An Error Occured while running detection" when i try to patch out sharepoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, administration, upgrade, farm

we have a SharePoint enterprise server 2013 and i installed the CU for March 2020 from Microsoft website @ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484280/march-10-2020-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013 , but when i try to install the CU i got this error:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things we might look around for this fix.

**Solution 1:**

This error usually occurs when the Windows Installer cache files (C:\Windows\Installer) are missing/corrupted. To further isolate the issue, you can try running ROISCAN on the machine and see how many installer cache files are missing. If these cache files were deleted manually during any housekeeping, it would be very difficult to restore the files. However if you have any other working environment (test/staging), you can copy the installer cache files and rename it according to the unique revision number from the registry keys associated with it. Luckily I could find a PowerShell script made by Ahmad Adel Gad herewhich will do this task for you. You simply have to:

Download the script.

Copy the script to the target machine.

Make sure that the current local identity has Read/Write permission on the "C:\Windows\Installer" folder of the target machine, and Read permission on the source folder (If the source is a machine name, make sure you have read permission on the local folder "C:\Windows\Installer" inside the source machine).

Execute the script locally on the target machine with the following parameters as illustrated with the following examples.

.\Restore-InstallerFiles.ps1 -SourceMachine "Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3";

.\Restore-InstallerFiles.ps1 -SourceFolder "D:\InstallerFiles", "E:\InstallerFiles", "\MachineX\D$\MSI Files";

.\Restore-InstallerFiles.ps1 -SourceFolder "D:\InstallerFiles", "E:\InstallerFiles", "D:\InstallerFiles2" -LogFile "D:\Log.txt";

Source of the above solution :

["An error Occured while Running detection" Sp2013 upgrade SP1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117222/an-error-occured-while-running-detection-sp2013-upgrade-sp1)

**Solution 2**

Try to download the patches one more time, there is slight possibility that downloaded files might have corrupted.

Here is a details steps to fix this issue :

[An Error Occurred While Running Detection when patching SharePoint Servers](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/02/error-occurred-running-detection-patching-sharepoint-servers/)

**Solution 3**

In general, if we go to this path **c:\windows\installer** folder -  we might see this path might have corrupted or have missing files.

Copy the c:\windows\installer folder from another working SharePoint server into a local c:\temp\ folder onto your bad server.

Follow the below steps :

Copy the script above into a file. I suggest using a text editor like Notepad++ instead of regular notepad. I tried copying the code into Notepad and I got errors because Notepad reads certain characters as ASCII characters so when you try to run it as a .vbs script, it returns error: unknown characters. Or you can download it from me: OpUtil.txt. Open it, look at it if you want, but be sure to rename it as a .vbs file instead of a .txt. Also put this script into your c:\temp\ folder for organization.

Open up command prompt on your bad server. Navigate to c:\windows\installer and run the following command:

runas /user:DOMAIN\Admin_Account “cscript.exe c:\temp\OpUtil.vbs /RepairCache /srestorelocation=c:\temp\”

Open up a PowerShell window and run Get-SPProduct -local to update the farm’s configuration database.

Run psconfig.exe to update everything and now you should be ready to install your updates.

Above solution is from :

[An error occurred while running detection.](https://sharepointprabhakaran.blogspot.com/2017/05/an-error-occurred-while-running.html?m=1)